# FFmpeg is "unable to find a suitable output format for '–i'"

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to do a simple conversion using the following arguments [from Fabio Sonnati's blog](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-ii/).

```
ffmpeg –i source.MOV –r 15 –s 320×240 –an video.flv
```

Getting this error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '–i'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit lies in the blog post itself. The author used the [en-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En-dash) instead of the [hypen-minus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) (`–`, not `-`), so FFmpeg will choke on that and not recognize `i` as the input option.

Moreover, the author used the [multiplication sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%97) instead of a latin `x` for the size (`×`, not `x`).

To fix this, replace the command with:

```
ffmpeg -i source.MOV -r 15 -s 320x240 -an video.flv
```

And go write the author a mail that they should fix their examples.